# Is there a way to detect the version of Windows in a build.rs?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

As the title says. I'm building some C files in my build.rs and I need to conditionally set some defines / conditionally link libraries depending on the version of Windows. Is there a way to detect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. 
There is for example the [nt_version crate](https://docs.rs/nt_version/), which you can use to detect the windows version **at compile time**. Please note, that you might "cross compile" for a different windows version (e.g. develop on Windows 7 for Windows 10 or similar).

Here's a small snippet on how you could use it:

```rust
use nt_version;

fn main() {
    let version: &str;
    match nt_version::get() {
        (6, 0, _) => version = "Windows Vista",
        (6, 1, _) => version = "Windows 7",
        (10, _, _) => version = "Windows 10",
        _ => version = "Unsupported!",
    }

    println!("cargo:warning={}", version);
}
```